# IF statement to copy over text if it says 'delivered' or 'OFD'

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am just trying to work out if I can use an IF statement to do this or if I am going in the wrong area.

What I need is that if cell `A1` contains the text `delivered` or `OFD` copy that into cell `A2`, this might seem real simple but I just can't seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

A different interpretation of "contains" might allow a shorter formula:

```
=IF(OR(A1="delivered",A1="OFD"),A1,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("delivered",A1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("OFD",A1),0)>0,A1,"")
```